# Restore a azure database from outside using python

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-python

Is there any way to restore an azure database by calling from outside. 
My database is backed up automatically, I want to use that back up to restore to a new database.

That is perfect if I can do this by using Python.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to create a new database from a point-in-time restore of an existent database.

Sample request.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-SouthEastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr/databases/dbpitr?api-version=2017-10-01-preview
```

Request body.

```
{
  "location": "southeastasia",
  "sku": {
    "name": "S0",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "properties": {
    "createMode": "PointInTimeRestore",
    "sourceDatabaseId": "/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-SouthEastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr/databases/testdb",
    "restorePointInTime": "2017-07-14T05:35:31.503Z"
  }
}
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#creates-a-database-from-pointintimerestore.) you will find more information:

Comment: Thank for your answer. Is it impossible to restore to another server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `azure-sdk-for-python` to manage your database and restore to specific subscription:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient

def main():
    client = SqlManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id="00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444",
    )

    response = client.databases.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name="myrsg",
        server_name="testsvr",
        database_name="testdw",
        parameters={
            "location": "northeurope",
            "properties": {
                "createMode": "PointInTimeRestore",
                "restorePointInTime": "2024-01-22T05:35:31.503Z",
                "sourceResourceId": "/subscriptions/55555555-6666-7777-8888-999999999999/resourceGroups/myrsg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/srcsvr/databases/srcdw",
            },
        },
    ).result()
    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```